# MariaDB in the cloud....need some guidance

Tags: innodb, cloud, mariadb-10.6

my plan is to move a mariadb into the cloud in germany. the clients will connect to it from 2 different office locations with 1gig/50mb up/dowload cable internet.  Approx 10 clients will use the cloudDB with the connector /net. the database size is 2 TB right now and sqlite.

The DB provider must be in germany .

Can anybody guide me in the right direction please.   managed server or VServer? Hardware config? Storage space ? I want to avoid pitfalls.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided, at least 4TB of disk on your server.  The rest depends on the complexity and frequency of queries, plus the size of the result sets.  The number of CPU cores is not likely to be a problem.